# jooq nested select and type safety

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to write the following sql in jooq:

```sql
SELECT SUM(`sum`) AS `total`
FROM(
        SELECT
        MIN(`num_views`) AS `sum`
        FROM `fact_wishlist`
        GROUP BY `id`
) AS t
```

I've found something that works with this:

```java
Table<Record2<String, Integer>> nested = 
    table(create.select(MYTABLE.ID,
    min(MYTABLE.NUM_VIEWS)
            .as("views"))
    .from(MYTABLE)
    .groupBy(MYTABLE.ID));

return create.select(sum((Field<Integer>) nested.field("views")))
    .from(nested)
    .fetchOne().value1().longValue();
```

However, somehow I've lost the type safety. I feel I'm doing something obvious wrong, but I'm not seeing it. Any ideas on how this could be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot achieve 100% type safety with derived tables in jOOQ, as the Java compiler cannot really prove that a derived table contains a column. But your usage can definitely be improved by reusing the `"views"` field. Just assign it to a local variable.

```java
Field<Integer> views = min(MYTABLE.NUM_VIEWS).as("views");

Table<Record2<String, Integer>> nested = 
    table(create.select(MYTABLE.ID, min(views))
    .from(MYTABLE)
    .groupBy(MYTABLE.ID));

return create.select(sum(nested.field(views)))
    .from(nested)
    .fetchOne().value1().longValue();
```

Notice how the [`Table.field(Field<T>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#field-org.jooq.Field-) method allows for maintaining the `<T>` type reference assuming that the field you pass in really exists in the derived table, by its given name, and that it matches the type of your argument field.

#### Alternative using window functions

Notice that your query could be rewritten using [window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/) as follows.

```
SELECT SUM(MIN(num_views)) OVER ()
FROM fact_wishlist
GROUP BY id
LIMIT 1
```

Or in jOOQ:

```java
return
create.select(sum(min(MYTABLE.NUM_VIEWS)).over())
      .from(MYTABLE)
      .groupBy(MYTABLE.ID)
      .limit(inline(1))
      .fetchSingle()
      .value1().longValue();
```

This of course depends on whether your database supports window functions, and it might be faster/slower than your double aggregation solution, also depending on the vendor.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. The over() version would work for me, and although I find it less intuitive it's definitely more concise, so I'm going with that :)